# Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c#, fibonacci

So I have this problem where I have to calculate the Fibonacci number of any given number from the user. I don't know how to do the actual calculations part, but everything else works. Here's my code. Can someone help me with the calculation part?

```
using System;

namespace Assignment
{
  class MainClass
  {
     public static void Main (string[] args)
     {
       int sum = 0;
       Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci Number: ");
       String fib = Console.ReadLine ();
       double result = Convert.ToDouble (fib);
       for(int i = 0; i <= result; i++)
       {
         sum = i * i - 1;
       }
       Console.WriteLine ("!" + result + " = " + sum);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: "What's wrong with the calculations part?" Hint: [does it follow the definition?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: It's your assignment, so it's you who supposed to do that. Ask your professor about help

Comment: There is a .Net Perl article that should help -http://www.dotnetperls.com/fibonacci

Comment: Ask the user for the number they’d like to get the Fibonacci of.
 The Fibonacci of a number is the product of all the numbers from 1 until that number
multiplied together
 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120 (Where ! means Fibonacci).

Comment: This is what i need to do. How do i fix it? I just need to change how i get my sum variable

Comment: @user2901139 That [looks like Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) .. please review the two articles I have linked.

Answer (score 2):

Extension on recursion approach - use [anonymous recursion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)  (which uses Fibonacci as example of recursive call):

Define recursive function: `f(n+1) = f(n) + f(n-1);`.

Grab definition of Y-Combinator from the article:

```
delegate Func<A,R> Recursive<A,R>(Recursive<A,R> r);
static Func<A, R> Y<A, R>(Func<Func<A, R>, Func<A, R>> f)
{
  Recursive<A, R> rec = r => a => f(r(r))(a);
  return rec(rec);
}
```

Now use Y-combinator to construct recursive function:

```
Func<int,int> fib = Y<int,int>(f => n => n > 1 ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : n);
```

Ready to call:

```
var fibOfSmallNumber = fib(4);
```

Now for large values you'd need [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Func<BigInteger,BigInteger> fibForBigNumbers = 
    Y<BigInteger,BigInteger>(f => n => n > 1 ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : n);
var fibOfBigNumber = fib(4);
```

Don't expect it to return value in short amount of time - default recursive implementation is very slow. Instead you should apply [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to remember previous values of the function (which also covered in the article).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the definition of the Fibonacci numbers? Please look them up; they have nothing to do with the polynomial *x² - 1*. The point of the problem is for you to translate the algorithm into C♯.

There are three general approaches you'll find:

1. Iteration by a for loop.
2. Recursion.
3. Direct formulas using exponentiation.

Try it all three ways.  I suggest you look at the textbook by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*. You'll learn some of the history too.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the nth fibonacci number something like this should work:

```
const double goldenratio = 1.6180339887;
int n = 16;
int nthfib = Math.Round(Math.Pow(goldenratio, n - 1) / Math.Sqrt(5));
```

nthfib will equal the 16th fibonacci number, 610.

Since the fibonacci sequence gets very large rather quickly, you might need a limit set on n so that nthfib doesn't max out.